# SQL Cumulative Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, running-count

I have table with departments. I need to count how many people are within which dept. This is easily done by

```sql
SELECT DEPT,
       COUNT(*) as 'Total'
    FROM SR
    GROUP BY DEPT;
```

Now I need to also do cumulative count as below:

[image]

I have found some SQL to count running total, but not case like this one. Could you provide me some advice in this case, please?

Comment: can you add schema of you table or do you have any primary key ??

Comment: I guess this thread was not offered to you as you typed your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver  By the way, my google search string was, "sql server running totals".

Comment: @Dhaval - there is no PK nor row numbers as the data are being historized via SCD.

Comment: And if you didn't know the term "running total", you could very well search for "sql server cumulative count", that would give you *plenty* of suggestions as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with a CTE instead of a cursor:

```
WITH Base AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Count] DESC) RowNum,
    [Dept],
    [Count]
    FROM SR
)
SELECT SR.Dept, SR.Count, SUM(SR2.[Count]) Total
FROM Base SR
INNER JOIN Base SR2
    ON SR2.RowNum <= SR.RowNum
GROUP BY SR.Dept, SR.Count
ORDER BY SR.[Count] DESC
```

Note that this is ordering by descending `Count` like your sample result does.  If there's some other column that's not shown that should be used for ordering just replace `Count` in each of the `ORDER BY` clauses.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0771/1/0)

Comment: Great, this works perfectly for my needs. Is there also possibility to "easily" add another derived column next to the cumulative count, which would count the (cumulative_count / sum [per_all_depts]) for each row? In the meaning of cumulative_count / 254. The result should be shown as percentage.

Comment: Done, found it by myself. Thanks again, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use some temporary / variable table for this, and use solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver/13744550#13744550):

```
declare @Temp table (rn int identity(1, 1) primary key, dept varchar(128), Total int)

insert into @Temp (dept, Total)
select
    dept, count(*) as Total
from SR
group by dept

;with cte as (
    select T.dept, T.Total, T.Total as Cumulative, T.rn
    from @Temp as T
    where T.rn = 1
    union all
    select T.dept, T.Total, T.Total + C.Cumulative as Cumulative, T.rn
    from cte as C
        inner join @Temp as T on T.rn = C.rn + 1
)
select C.dept, C.Total, C.Cumulative
from cte as C
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22709)</kbd>**

There're some other solutions, but this one is fastest for SQL Server 2008, I think.

Comment: @ypercube nice article, thank you, but actually, in this article, cursor approach is 2 times slower than CTE (but it has less I/O operations)

Comment: Yes, right, I read the pictures wrong. I was sure (in my memory) it was the other way around. Perhaps I had discarded CTE method because it needs consecutive numbers (that you get through the temp table and IDENTITY.) Link again to the article discussed in these comments: [Best approaches for running totals.](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)

Comment: @ypercube yeah, cte is a bit less code than a cursor, but it needs numbers/other keys without gaps

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to add an identity column to the table - then the solution is easier;

```
create table #SQLCumulativeCount
(
 id int identity(1,1),
 Dept varchar(100),
 Count int
)
insert into #SQLCumulativeCount (Dept,Count) values ('PMO',106)
insert into #SQLCumulativeCount (Dept,Count) values ('Finance',64)
insert into #SQLCumulativeCount (Dept,Count) values ('Operations',41)
insert into #SQLCumulativeCount (Dept,Count) values ('Infrastructure',22)
insert into #SQLCumulativeCount (Dept,Count) values ('HR',21)

select *,
   sum(Count) over(order by id rows unbounded preceding) as Cumulative 
from #SQLCumulativeCount
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with Base as (
select 
    dept, 
    count, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by count desc) as RowNum
from SR
)
select 
    dept, 
    count, 
    sum(count) over(order by RowNum) as Cumulative
from Base
```